# Word Problem: Probability of Y books Fitting in Book Case

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, stochastic-calculus

**Problem**:

> You have $4600$ cm of book case. The thickness of the books are
> independently distributed with $X \sim N(1.8$ cm$,0.7^2)$.
>
> Approximately
> determine what the probability of having more than 2500 books is.

**My solution so far**:

> My first thought is to define a new random variable for the amount of
> books $Y$~$N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, and then determine $\mathbb{P}(Y>2500)$. But how
> do I relate $X$'s known distribution to $Y$'s unknown one?

Comment: Hint: central limit theorem

Comment: Yes, but Central Limit Theorem only states the probability of the SUM being less or greather than some constants. It's not the sum that is the interesting variable here, but the amount of additions Y.

Comment: The number of books = amount of space/total thickness of the books https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution#Reciprocal_normal_distribution

Comment: Oh, so Y:=4600/X?

Comment: That is correct, yes.

Comment: But an inverse normal distributed random variable doesn't have a mean and variance it says?

Comment: What difference does that make? You want to calculate $\mathbb{P}(Y>2500)$, not any of the moments of the distribution. The distribution function is still defined.

Comment: No, you want the probability that at least 2500 books can fit on the shelf length 4600 cm.  $Y_N$ is the length of $N$ books.  Find $\mathsf P(Y_{2500}\leq 4600)$ when $Y_N = \sum_{k=1}^N X_k$.

Comment: There is a hidden assumption in the question, which is that the bookcase is full.  I know people who have never bought $250$ books in their lives. I agree that the intended reading is "What is the probability that the total width of $2500$ books is less than $4600$ cm?".

Answer (score 1):

You have that $X_k\sim\mathcal N(1.8\textrm{cm},0.7^2\textrm{cm}^2)$ independently for all $\{X_k\}_{k\in\Bbb N^+}$ being the widths of books to be placed on a shelf of length $4600$cm.

Now, let $Y_N=\sum_{k=1}^N X_k$ , and so $Y_N \sim \mathcal N(1.8\textrm{cm}\,N, 0.7^2\textrm{cm}^2\,N)$

$Y_N$ is thus the combined width of $N$ books.

You want to find the probability that at least $2500$ books can fit on the shelf of the given length.  $$\mathsf P(Y_{2500}\leq 4600)$$

Comment: I have the same question as Samuel Larsson, and I don't find your answer being sufficient. Could you elaborate on how $P(Y_{2500}\leq4600)$ is computed? Note that the length of the books stacked next to each other should be exactly 4600 cm, not less than or equal to 4600 cm.

Comment: @OskarTegby The bookshelf can contains $more$ than 2500 books only if the total width of the books $Y \le 4600$

Comment: @user137481: Perhaps this is a different question. The length of the books stacked next to each others is exactly 4600 cm. That doesn't make much sense as that probability is 0, but that is how the question is phrased. I still wonder how $P(Y_{2500}\leq4600)$ is computed. If I can obtain that value I can check with the key to see that the answer is correct indeed.

Comment: @OskarTegby Note that $Y$ ~ $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and $P(Y \le 4600)$ is the same as $P(\frac{Y-u}{\sigma} \le \frac{4600-\mu}{\sigma})$. Now, use the standard normal tables to find $P(Z \le \frac{4600-\mu}{\sigma})$ where $Z$ ~ $N(0, 1)$

Comment: Okay, but what are $\mu$ and $\sigma$ here? Aren't they $\mu=1.8N$ and $\sigma=0.49N$? Thus, dependent on $N$.

Comment: @OskarTegby $N=2500, \mu = 1.8N, \sigma=\sqrt{0.49N}=35$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67018/discussion-between-oskar-tegby-and-user137481).